When I saving a scene, the scene is excluded from the build setting
When change and save scene, it is remove from the list of scenes in the build setting.
This is the 6000.0.2f1 version.
I thought it would be a problem if I modified some options.
But even if I make a new project and test it, there is the same problem.

sounds like a bug for unity, but with that as a description they would reject it as that is not enough for reproducible steps, as tbn if scenes couldnt be added, there'd have been hell to pay .. also 6000.03f is out, and contains a bunch of other fixes
